# CREATE DATABASE mynewdb

Tags: oracle

```
    CREATE DATABASE mynewdb USER SYS IDENTIFIED BY sys_password USER SYSTEM 
    IDENTIFIED BY system_password LOGFILE GROUP 1 
    ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/redo01.log') SIZE 100M, GROUP 2 
    ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/redo02.log') SIZE 100M, GROUP 3 
    ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/redo03.log') SIZE 100M;
```

and SQL rejects this and show this error:

> CREATE DATABASE mynewdb *
>   ERROR at line 1: ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed
>   ORA-01504: database name 'MYNEWDB' does not match parameter db_name 'orcl'

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Add in your PFILE or SPFILE:

```
db_name=MYNEWDB
```